# Activemq, Http Client : Socket Read timeout

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-servicemix

We have one Broker1 networkconnecting with Broker2 having one client.

After some hours consumer is not consuming messages. To consume from test client we used a simple client. On broker side we are not getting any error [ this might be because we have not enabled proper logs. We enabled all of this stacktrace logs]

Service MIX : 
apache-servicemix-5.6.0 { AMQ 5.12.3 org.apache.httpcomponents HttpClient - 4.5.1  org.apache.httpcomponents HttpCore  - 4.4.4 Camel - 2.16 Spring - 3.2.14} 
few messages we are able to consume after that getting below error

```
receiving
javax.jms.JMSException: Failed to perform GET on: https://URL Reason: Read timed out
    at org.apache.activemq.util.JMSExceptionSupport.create(JMSExceptionSupport.java:72)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dequeue(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:476)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:557)
    at org.apache.activemq.recipes.SimpleJMS.run(SimpleJMS.java:108)
    at org.apache.activemq.recipes.SimpleJMS.main(SimpleJMS.java:128)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to perform GET on: https://URL Reason: Read timed out
    at org.apache.activemq.util.IOExceptionSupport.create(IOExceptionSupport.java:33)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.run(HttpClientTransport.java:205)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:961)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:918)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:92)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:62)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:252)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:191)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:784)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.http.HttpClientTransport.run(HttpClientTransport.java:178)`enter code here`
    ... 1 more
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:775)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1292)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1251)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1163)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createConsumer(ActiveMQSession.java:1135)
    at org.apache.activemq.recipes.SimpleJMS.run(SimpleJMS.java:103)
    at org.apache.activemq.recipes.SimpleJMS.main(SimpleJMS.java:128)
```

Full log can be found here: https://pastebin.com/xjNc46y9

Comment: here is the link for error as I am not able to post using this link providing here : https://pastebin.com/xjNc46y9